# How to make a specific user-defined function in R

Tags: r

I want to create a function that takes three data points to produce a fraction. Specifically, I want (variable A - variable B)/(variable C - variable B).

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html

Answer (score 1):

Short functions as the one you mentioned, can be expressed in a single line

```
frct <- function(a, b, c) (a-b)/(c-b)
```

so you can save the `{}` brackets. If you have more complex functions, the introduction of the `return`-statement is wise to control the value(s) that are returend from your function (if you need multiple return values, put them in a `list` first).

You can then call your function without naming the arguments explicitly, like

```
frct(1,2,3)
```

which will give you `-1` as result.

Answer (score 0):

```
myfunction <- function(A, B, C) {
    (A-B)/(C-B)
}
```

To be clear, call it in the standard way:

```
myfunction(A = 3, B = 1, C = 3)
```

> 1